# Editing one column of table based off another

Tags: applescript, numbers, iwork

It seems like something that should be simple, and it probably is but my mind is being dense and not helping me. I have a table with two columns. The first acts as a master list of titles, and the second acts as a list of titles used. I simply want a way to remove everything that has been used from the master list so that the first table no longer contains them. Can someone help me with a script or simple way to do this?

Have tried scripts when I had this both on one table:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    tell front document
        tell sheet 1
            set masterList to value of cells of column "B"
            set usedList to value of cells of column "C"
            
            repeat with i from (count of masterList) to 1 by -1
                set masterItem to item i of masterList
                if masterItem is in usedList then
                    delete cell i of column "B"
                end if
            end repeat
            
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Here's how it is set up:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points…

- You need to work with both the cell references and the cell values
- Numbers doesn't allow you to delete a cell
- You need to specify the table in the script, not merely the sheet

What this script does is cycles through each value of the usedList and cycle through the masterList to see if there is a match. Both lists are reversed so later entries are processed first but given that you can't delete cells, this might not produce any benefit.

When it finds a matching cell in the masterList, it clears the value and then moves on to the next entry in the usedList — so it assumes that there will be only a single match for each usedList item.

If you want to put the usedList into a second table, you can do so by including 'table 2' in any references to the usedList. If the two are in separate tables, then it might make it easier to sort the resulting masterList, and thus push the blank cells down below any with a remaining value.

```
-- Editing one column of table based off another
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    tell front document
        tell sheet 1
            tell table 1
                sort by column 2 -- if already sorted, then remove
                set hrc1 to header row count
                set frc1 to footer row count
                
                -- exclude blank cells at bottom
                set mcc to (count (cells of column 2 whose value is not missing value)) - frc1
                set mbr to range ("B2:B" & mcc as text) -- construct master data range
                set vmr to value of cells of mbr -- list of master values
            end tell
            
            tell table 2 -- should also be sorted
                sort by column 2 -- if already sorted, then remove
                set hrc2 to header row count
                set frc2 to footer row count
                
                -- exclude blank cells at bottom
                set ucc to (count (cells of column 2 whose value is not missing value)) - frc2
                set ubr to range ("B2:B" & ucc as text) -- construct used data range
                set vur to value of cells of ubr -- list of used values
            end tell
            
            set lenVmr to length of vmr
            set mc to 0
            repeat with uc from 1 to length of vur -- cycle through used values
                repeat -- cycle through master values
                    set mc to mc + 1
                    if (item uc of vur) is equal to (item mc of vmr) then -- if values match
                        clear cell mc of mbr -- clear matching cell in master table
                        exit repeat
                    end if
                    if mc is equal to lenVmr then exit repeat
                end repeat
                if mc is equal to lenVmr then exit repeat
            end repeat
            -- after all matching cells have been cleared
            sort table 1 by column 2 of table 1
        end tell -- sheet
    end tell -- document
end tell -- numbers
```

**Update:**
I made some changes to the script and it should be quicker with larger tables. On my old system, it took about 110 seconds to process a master list of 2000 records and a used list of 500 records. Most computers should be faster than mine so take that into account.

I suggest trying it on a small table to first confirm that it is doing what is desired and to get a feel for performance.

I also separated it into two tables, as per the question.

What it does now is, after sorting, generate a list of the values in each column and then cycle through both lists, taking each used value and finding the matching value in the master list. It then clears the corresponding cell. As the lists are sorted, it should begin each cycle where the last one left off so there should be no more than one cycle per master list item. By working with the lists rather than the tables, it means that it only goes back to the table when clearing each matching cell.

After clearing all the matched cells, it will re-sort.

**Update 2:**
Add an exit repeat to outside loop as well. Apparently, it should only trigger when a late item on the master side is a match, as this event causes the first exit to be skipped. Without that, the loops will cycle with an item that doesn't exist, causing the error mentioned.

Comment: I tried this out and it just hung up and never quit running, even after 30 minutes, and hadn't removed any of the cells.

Comment: No need to wait that long — bail after a minute. How many rows in your table? FWIW, as is, while it worked fine for me with a small table, it doesn't scale very efficiently. I'll update a revision later today.

Comment: So I tried this out and I got:

`error "Can’t get item 1541 of {\"A Beautiful Life\", //and then proceeds to name every file in master list"`

Comment: I added an image to hopefully clear up anything for how it is constructed

Comment: Does your list have 1540 items? I think that error suggests that it's including the header in the count of items, and therefore thinks that there are more rows than there actually are — ie, instead of rows of data, it's using rows. Need to stop the cycling one cycle earlier.

Comment: yes, 1540 items

Comment: The layout helped, especially with this particular error. FWIW, I think you can enter the actual table data (ie table1:columnB and table2:columnC) and it will be automatically formatted and thus easier to work with. I ended up running OCR on the image. Give it a try now and let me know.

Comment: By the way, while I was right about the cycling, I was wrong about the cause. The earlier script (v2) would exit the inner loop with each match. The way it was set up, when the match is at the bottom, it would skip the exit and begin a new cycle, which of course starts with an item that doesn't exist. Have to check and see what happens if both lists end with the last match.

Comment: I just tried the updated script and no errors, but it also didn't remove any items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152014/discussion-between-mockman-and-user717452).